# Java: For statement inside of Do statement?

Tags: java, for-loop, do-while

This is related to my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829034/java-how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-part-of-any-linkedlist-element)

```
  public void equipWep(String weapontoequip){
    if(items.isEmpty() && weapons.isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("You are not carrying anything.");
    } else {
      boolean weaponcheck_finished = false;
      do {
        for (String s : weapons) {
          if (s.contains(weapontoequip)) {
            System.out.println("You equip " + s + ".");
            weaponcheck_finished = true;
          } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot equip \"" + weapontoequip + "\", or you do not have it.");
            weaponcheck_finished = true;
          }
        }
      }while(weaponcheck_finished == false);
    }
  }
```

When this method runs, System does not print anything out. Through a series of print tests, I have determined that it goes inside of the `do-while` loop. I'm not sure if it goes inside the `for` loop though.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger instead of just print statements?

Comment: That's a mess to read, and full of various naming conventions. But if there are any weapons, it goes inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your items might contain something, but your weapons may be empty. Your code doesn't seem to do anything in this case.

Comment: @QuanChi So that was the only issue?

Comment: @QuanChi Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Start from here instead:

```
public void equipWithWeapon(String weapon) {
    if (items.isEmpty() && weapons.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You are not carrying anything.");
        return;
    }

    String foundWeapon = findWeapon(weapon);
    if (foundWeapon == null) {
        System.out.println("You cannot equip \"" + weapon + "\", or you do not have it.");
    }

    System.out.println("You equip " + foundWeapon + ".");
}

private String findWeapon(String weapon) {
    for (String s : weapons) {
        if (s.contains(weapon)) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```